# Collecting training data for land cover classification

Tags: arcgis-desktop, land-use, agriculture

I want to begin mapping various land cover such as coconut and pine. My issue is I do not have much experience in terms of collecting land use information or analyzing satellite imagery and analysis.

What is the preferred method to collect training data suitable for land cover classification of satellite imagery?

Answer (score 1):

For beginners to start with Land Cover Classification, you can use Landsat Dataset that is freely available and also in good resolution of about 30m with a Panchromatic band of 15m Resolution.

You can Download Dataset for different landsat sensor from http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/. Your can create a free account, and Download data.

Once You have downloaded the dataset. You can use ESRI Products. You can get more info about ESRI product at http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis.

This is commercial software but you can still get Trial License for this. 
You can also use Open Source softwares for Land cover classificaiton.